# Python - Декодировать байты b'v106\x94{\xec\xe3

Tags: python, sqlite, byte, decode, encoder

Всем привет! Есть такие байты:

```py
b'v10\x9d.j\xa79\xb9\x9b\xa8\xd6\xc4_\xfc\x8ao\x8c\xb8b+\xeb\x98ic*f$\xff\xee\xddj4\xa7n\x19\xf2\x95'
```

Получаю их из БД SQLite с помощью python-пакета `sqlite3`. В ячейке, где содержатся эти значения, находится `BLOB`. При нажатии на `BLOB` в окне [редактирования ячейки](https://sun9-3.userapi.com/impg/Hoze1JgYLfevW7NdOR-XHbO3_ZKJGhgy1dMDSA/k3zDSPYe8ys.jpg?size=748x319&quality=96&sign=70088e0354d3b9f79d9bffba9e1e735b&type=album) отображаются двоичные данные.

Вопрос: Как эти полученные из БД байты/двоичные данные превратить в читабельный английский текст?

UPD: С помощью `binascii.hexlify()` удалось превратить данные в строку `7631309D2E6AA739B99BA8D6C45FFC8A6F8CB8622BEB9869632A6624FFEEDD6A34A76E19F295`. Может быть эту строку будет легче декодировать?

Comment: Почему вы решили, что это вообще возможно превратить в читабельный текст?

Comment: Ну в интернете видел инфу про decode и encode, все перепробовал, ничего не получилось. Вообще я эти данные из БД с помощью sqlite3 получаю, их нужно превратить в английские  буквы. В самой БД они зашифрованы, через программу "DB Browser for SQLite" там отображается BLOB

Comment: Почему вы решили, что что-то вообще может получиться?

Comment: Ну вроде Python хорошо работает со строками и кодировками, поэтому, мне кажется, и должно получиться

Comment: Получиться что?

Comment: Декодировать эту строку в нормальные английские буквы (нормальную кодировку). Если быть точным - должна получиться строка `admin`.

Comment: Тогда смотрите, кто, где, и как их закодировал, потому что без технических подробностей гадать можно бесконечно

Comment: binascii.hexlify это наоборот кодирование. Вы можете бесконечно кодировать что угодно во что угодно, но это не будет иметь никакого практического смысла и никакого отношения к исходным данным

Comment: Но в любом случае мне кажется способ получить из [двоичных данных](https://sun9-3.userapi.com/impg/Hoze1JgYLfevW7NdOR-XHbO3_ZKJGhgy1dMDSA/k3zDSPYe8ys.jpg?size=748x319&quality=96&sign=70088e0354d3b9f79d9bffba9e1e735b&type=album) нормальный текст должен быть

Comment: Не должен, в общем случае это может оказаться абсолютно случайный ничего не значащий набор байтов. Если же у вас есть уверенность что это не так, то задавайте вопрос тому, кто создал эти байты